# Flash Player 64bit

Tags: 64-bit, flash

Is there a way to use a Flash Player (on something like it... something what can play videos from YouTube, etc) in a Firefox 64bit build? Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a 32 bit browser according to Adobe - http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/000/6b3af6c9.html

Comment: Yeah, I've read it. But is there a way, maybe some hack, etc?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't that I've ever seen. Supposedly there is an x64 Linux Flash player coming soon though, which means a Windows one can't be far away.